# Unable to send e-mails using SMTP

Tags: smtp

I am not being able to send e-mails through EE (I am using version 2.1.3 Build 20101220).

I just want my application to relay to an external SMTP server.

I am editing both these files:
\expressionengine\libraries\EE_Email.php
\codeigniter\system\libraries\Email.php

Is there any other file to look at?

Best regards,

Answer (score 4):

Why are you hacking core files? Why not just set the mail preferences to use SMTP?

Go to Admin->Email Configuration, select SMTP for your email protocol and enter any necessary authentication info in the fields provided.

Comment: For sure. I can't think of one instance I would recommend on this site to hack the EE core, let alone the CodeIgniter core.

Comment: Need to use a port other than 25 when sending Email via SMTP. Yes, modifying a core file is bad, but sometimes when your hands are cuffed you got to do what you got to do. That being said this probably not the case here.

Comment: You can simply add the port number to the hostname in the SMTP set up within the EE control panel. For instance, I'm using Mandrill with a project I'm currently working on and have set the SMTP hostname to smtp.mandrillapp.com:587  it works perfectly.